# Building a function from an arbitrary callable with a matching reflection in PHP

Tags: php, reflection

Lets say I have an arbitrary function taking some parameters and returning say an array (the return and what the method does doesn't matter)

```php
$callable = fn (MyClass $myClass, string $id, bool $rec) => []
```

I would like to build a new function from this closure so that this new function takes the exact same parameters in a way that the Reflection of this function will have the same parameters as the original

What I mean:

```php
$clonedCallable = someMagic($callable);
assertEquals( // Equal but obviously not the same ref
  (new ReflectionFunction($callable))->getParameters(),
  (new ReflectionFunction($clonedCallable))->getParameters()
);
$callable(); // []
$clonedCallable(); // Wrapper([])
```

I'm basically trying to wrap a closure, in a way that would not lose reflection information

```php
fn (...$args) => $callable(...$args); // This would not work
fn (MyClass $myClass, string $id, bool $rec) => $callable($myClass, $id, $rec); // I need to generate this
```

Is there a way in PHP to build this kind of method without using some hackjob eval (which is the only idea I have right now) as Reflection doesn't have some kind of magic `setParameters()`?

Comment: Why not creating a class having that function?

Comment: I'm not trying to implement inheritance, I'm trying to build a proxy between a route definition and a route controller, the route definition uses the parameters of this arbitrary function to inject dependencies and route params correctly but I need to modify the return of the original function in that proxy which can take any parameters without being able to change the logic of the route injector

Comment: Short answer: a class would make that function not arbitrary with a fixed set of parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

   class Foo { }

   $add = function (int $a, Foo $foo): array {
             return [$a * 2];
         };

   function wrapAction(string|callable|array $action, callable $wrapper = null): callable
   {
        $rc = is_array($action) ?
            new ReflectionMethod($action[0], $action[1]) :
            new ReflectionFunction($action);
        $args = [];
        $action = $rc->getClosure();
        if (!$wrapper) {
            $wrapper = fn ($res) => $res;
        }
        foreach ($rc->getParameters() as $arg) {
            $args[] = $arg->getType() . ' $' . $arg->getName();
        }
        $args = join(',', $args);
        return eval("return fn ($args) => \$wrapper(\$action(...func_get_args()));"); // I know, but I can't think of any way other than this ;)
    }


   // test
   $clone = wrapAction($add, fn ($res) => $res + 2);
   $orgRef = new ReflectionFunction($add);
   $cloneRef = new ReflectionFunction($clone); 

   assert($orgRef->getParameters() == $cloneRef->getParameters(), "Not the same");

   $foo = new Foo();
   print_r($add(5, $foo)); // 10
   print_r($clone(5, $foo)); // 12
```

Comment: It should then be `return fn ({$args}) => $org(...func_get_args());` to preserve the proxy body, but yes that was my only eval idea as well but I'm not liking it one bit

Comment: I hope someone can help you out and I will be watching for the "perfect" solution. It is very easy to preserve the original function body with or without `fn`

Comment: I don't think there is one in this case, but thanks for helping out

Comment: I've modified your code to add a wrapper within, it works great, so for now that will have to do, I'll leave it not accepted for now because my question was specifically without eval, but if nobody can come up with a better answer in 2 days I'll accept it, sometimes some eval use is legit